# Ориентированный граф без визуализации

Tags: c++, c, графы

Привет.

Как можно написать ориентированный граф без визуализации через матрицу смежности или через каким нибудь другим методом?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxN 5

int main()
{
    int graph[maxN][maxN];

    int inf = 0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= maxN; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= maxN; j++) {
            graph[i][j] = inf;
        }
    }
    graph[3][1] = 5;
    graph[3][3] = 3;
    graph[3][4] = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= maxN; i++) // куда должно входить ребро
        if (graph[3, i] != inf) // если есть ребро, выходящее из 3, входящее в i
            printf("Rebro iz 3 v %d s vesom %d", i, graph[3, i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку.

> Stack around the variable 'graph' was corrupted.

Использую матрицу смежности. Как правильно вывести расстояние?

Comment: Тут на лицо повтор [вопроса](http://hashcode.ru/questions/108246/ориентированный-граф-с-расстояниями) и несоответсвие пункту о том, что вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. 

Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: `i<=maxN` исправьте на `i<maxN`

Comment: Либо int graph[maxN+1][maxN+1];

Comment: Судя по вашей задаче, список смежности был бы удобней.

Comment: Теперь не добавляет значение `grap[i][j]=value;`.

Comment: Если вы не прибавили, как делаю я. А как вам сказал @Spectre, тогда у вас вершины нумеруются с 0. И соответственно чтобы добавить, например, ребро (2,1) с весом 5. Вам надо `graph[1][0]=5`. В общем случае `graph[v-1][u-1]=Cost`.

Comment: При вводе итак он v-1 и при выводе тоже v-1. Все равно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Си — инструмент, острый, как бритва: с его помощью можно создать и элегантную программу, и кровавое месиво (Брайан Уилсон Керниган).

Помимо отмеченного в комментариях переполнения буфера (исправьте, как [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) предложил), в этой программе есть замечательный баг. При проверке наличия дуги и выводе вы пишете

```
graph[3, i]
```

тогда как нужно

```
graph[3][i]
```

Несмотря на наличие ошибки, с точки зрения синтаксиса языка C всё нормально. Результатом операции `3, i` является значение последнего выражения, то есть `i`. Обращение graph[i] тоже допустимо, только это будет адрес начала i-й строки. Этот адрес вы и выводите на экран. Результат ошибочной программы у меня выглядит так:

```
user@linux:~> ./a.out
Rebro iz 3 v 1 s vesom 1187739540Rebro iz 3 v 2 s vesom 1187739560Rebro iz 3 v 3
```

После исправления всё шоколадно:

```
user@linux:~> ./a.out
Rebro iz 3 v 1 s vesom 5Rebro iz 3 v 3 s vesom 3Rebro iz 3 v 4 s vesom 1
```

Вообще-то компилятор честно предупреждал, что что-то не так, внимательно читайте диагностику:

```
user@linux:~> gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:23: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

Comment: нифига!) круто спасибо!)