# Как  найти расстояние в графе от 1-й до 3-й вершины, если между ними есть вершина 2.

Tags: графы, c, c++

Привет.

Как  найти расстояние в графе от 1-й до 3-й вершины, если между ними есть вершина 2?

Например у меня имеется граф, a, b, c, d - вершины.

```
a b 3
a d 5
b c 6
a c 9
```

Здесь a - 1-я вершиная, b - 2-я вершина, 3 - расстояние (стоимость).
Как такое реализовать?

[Предыдущий вопрос с кодом программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/109485/%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Если построить матрицу смежности A, то для известных a, b, c, задача сведется к вычислению суммы A[a, b] + A[b, c].

Comment: Алгоритм Дейкстры использовать, нет?

Comment: алгоритм нахождения кратчайшего пути в графе? Не надо))

Comment: Из вопроса непонятно, может ли искомый путь из вершины 1 в вершину 3 содержать другие вершины, кроме второй.

Comment: я примерно спросил по идее. А так пока не надо)

Comment: а как в цикле это сделать? Т.е. для вершины а, перебираем всевозможные расстояния от него. Например, до b,до c, если путь от a до c лежит вершина b.

Comment: Чего вы обсуждаете? Дейкстра + рекурсивный алгоритм либо стек. Все.

Comment: @marioxxx, перебираете не расстояния, а связанные вершины.  
@RomanoO, если автору нужны только "друзья друзей", то реализовывать алгоритм Дейкстры - то же самое, что писать сервер управления базами данных, когда заказчику, нужно тупо считать строку из файла.